# how to update the subscribed channel for push notifications from parse in android programatically

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse for push notifications. so, what i did is, I subscribed to a channel named "EveryOne" while initilizing the parse with application id and client key.

The code goes like this in application class's onCreate() method:

```
    // Initialize Crash Reporting.
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_KEY);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("EveryOne", new SaveCallback()
    {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseException e)
          {
                if (e == null)
                {
                  Log.d("From ParseApplication", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                }
                else
                {
                  Log.e("From ParseApplication", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
          }
    });

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

### and for sending push notificaiton from app:

JSONObject obj;

```
    try
    {
        obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("action","app.package.name.PushNotification");
        obj.put("customdata","Message comes here");
        obj.put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());

        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();

        query.whereEqualTo("channels", "EveryOne");
        push.setQuery(query);
        push.setData(obj);
        push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback()
        {   
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0)
            {
                if(arg0 == null)
                {
```

//                      finish();
                        Log.d("if arg0", "arg0: "+arg0);

```
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Push Notificaiton Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("else arg0", "arg0: "+arg0);

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed To Send Push Notificaiton", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

because of this, who ever install the application, every one gets the push notification because of query:
 `query.whereEqualTo("channels", "EveryOne");`

So, now i want to update/delete the already subscribed channel from "EveryOne" to "IndividualOne" or "IndividualTwo" like this with different name(s) PROGRAMMATICALLY, so that i can send the push notifications to the selected ones rather than to every one by changing the query: 
`query.whereEqualTo("channels","IndividualTwo");`

Can anyone help me out in this..

Thank you in advance..